# Looping through a list to find an object with the largest number efficiently!

Tags: c#, algorithm, list, xna, physics

using c# i have a list   those objects all have a float mass that is randomized when the object is created.

Whats the most efficient way to loop through the list and find the object with the highest mass?

Comment: This would depend on how many times you want to access this information. What is the use case for this? Once off? Will you ever want to find out the lowest?

Comment: yess I was going to find the lowest as well later

Comment: Efficiency in terms of time or space?

Comment: The funny thing is, your question closes it down to exactly a single possible answer: 'the most efficient way to loop through the list' is, tadaaaa, to _loop through the list_

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most efficient way to do this with a simple list will be a simple linear time search, as in

```
SomeObject winner;
float maxMass = 0.0f; // Assuming all masses are at least zero!
foreach(SomeObject o in objects) {
    if(o.mass > maxMass) {
        maxMass = o.mass;
        winner = o;
    }
}
```

If this is something you intend to do regularly, it may be beneficial to store your objects in an order sorted by mass and/or to use a more appropriate storage container.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a perfect candidate for the MaxBy/MinBy operators in [morelinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/wiki/OperatorsOverview). You could use it as follows:

```
objects.MaxBy(obj=>obj.Mass)
```

Comment: @Mike: No it doesn't. The built-in LINQ stack `Max`/`Min` operators will only return the respective **value**, not the **object** it was found on.

Comment: @Mike: that applies only for primitive types, not if the maximum you are looking for is a property, in @spender's example `Mass`

Comment: @Mike: you might be confusing `MaxBy` with `Max`

Answer (score 1):

Implementing IComparable would make things simple and easy to maintain. I have provided an example. Hope this helps. 
I am not sure if this is more efficient than looping. I understand that sometimes using linq slightly degrades the performance for the first time when it is invoked.

But definitely many a times maintainable code scores more over slight performance gain. Can someone provide more details on performance of PARALLEL execution vs looping with AsParallel().

```
class Program
{
    delegate int Del();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<MyClass> connections = new List<MyClass>();
        connections.Add(new MyClass() { name = "a", mass = 5.001f });
        connections.Add(new MyClass() { name = "c", mass = 4.999f }); 
        connections.Add(new MyClass() { name = "b", mass = 4.2f });
        connections.Add(new MyClass() { name = "a", mass = 4.99f });

        MyClass maxConnection = connections.AsParallel().Max();
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} ", maxConnection.name, maxConnection.mass);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    class MyClass : IComparable
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public float mass { get; set; }

        public int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            return (int)(mass - ((MyClass)obj).mass);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to trade a little space for time then, in one of the instance constructors, have something like the following

```
public Foo(Foo min, Foo max)
{
   min = min ?? new Foo();  
   max = max ?? new Foo();

   if(max.mass < this.mass)
    max = this;

   if(min > this.mass)
    min = this;
}
```

And upon object creation have the calling method pass those paramters.

```
Foo min, max = null;

//Create a bunch of Foo objects

var Foos = from n in Enumerable.Range(0, 10000) select new Foo(min, max);
```

Comment: If you're gonna do this, simply insert it in an OrderedSet and pass a Comparer that compares by Mass; that way you'll have the answer (.First() and .Last()) and lot's more

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and most efficient solution (assuming repeated queries) is to sort the list by size.

i.e.

```
private int SortByMass(ObjectWithMass left,ObjectWithMass right)
{
  return left.Mass.CompareTo(right.Mass);
}    
List<ObjectWithMass> myList = MyFunctionToPopulateTheList();
myList.sort(SortByMass);
```

Once the list is sorted, the first element will be the smallest, and the last will be the largest. 
You can use `myList.Reverse()` if you want it by largest to smallest.

This runs in o(nlog(n)) to sort, and then finding the largest object is `myList[myList.Count -1]`. which is o(1) for .net lists (they are actually arrays underneath)